# Android talkback announce some words as character by character in nexus

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

In nexus device, Android accessibility "valid through" talkback as "'V' 'A' 'L' 'I' 'D' through". please share your thought why this happens in nexus?

We already checked it with some other versions of android devices but it is working fine.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your text upper cased?  Some screen readers will announce words in all caps as individual letters.

I don't know what kind of element you're having the problem on, but for an example, here's a workaround for a button.

```
<button aria-label="valid through">VALID through</button>
```

If you're using CSS to do a text transform to upper case, you shouldn't need a workaround but could still provide an `aria-label` if you wanted.

```
<button style="text-transform:uppercase">valid through</button>
<button style="text-transform:uppercase" aria-label="valid through">valid through</button>
```